# Multi select information on a data table

Tags: c#, charts

I have  spent a lot off time searching on the internet for this query had no luck..

using a visual studio form that shows a data-table with data.  currently i am able to select multiple cells on the client view using the ctrl button but was wondering if it would be possible in any other manner to allow users to select multiple cells.

after they have selected the data that they would like put this information back in and create a chart from this information.

using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to include a checkbox column within the datagrid?

Comment: I dont know to apply these properly.. so do u have any idea.i am a novice

Comment: Check this url. http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-checkbox.htm

Comment: i have added them was wondering how would i be able to check what checkbox have been selected.